# How to make a Drupal 7 module depend on a Theme by using modules .info file?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, dependencies

I am setting up a drupal 7 module which have to have dependency on a certain theme.

How can I achieve this in the modules .info file?

Comment: Pretty sure this feature doesn't exist. Also it's probably not best practice for a module to depend on a theme as it breaks the Separation of Concerns principle. If the module needs to theme it's own functionalit, then it should have it's own template files and theme functions.

Comment: OK, What do you think is a good practice when I'd like to use functions from a theme in my custom module? I use bootsrap that has code I can use in my module like markups, etc. to create lets say a button of the style I'd like?

Comment: In general your module should generate the raw content e.g. tpl.php files with HTML. Then in your theme you can apply bootstrap styles and JS to that HTML. If you need the styles applied in the module for some reason you could use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library to give access to bootstrap features in your modules.